# Requiring author feedback to solve the triage dilemma

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage

### TL;DR

Many of us agree that at the moment the triage queue does not work as it should. A lot of questions marked with **Should be Improved** cannot be improved by the community and are therefore stuffing the **Help and Improvement** queue.

It seems that the opinion now shifts towards renaming the buttons and start closing more aggressively.

I argue that this is not the best strategy and would like to propose a different approach that involves notifying the authors and hiding questions.

### Proposal

In my opinion closing and down-voting too aggressively has the potential to make Stack Overflow a hostile place for beginners. I agree that there are really, really bad questions that can and should be closed right away. But often the question is not that bad.

From my experience it is very common for new users to forget to include the traceback. Do we really want to close such a question as **Unclear what you're asking** right away?

I think there is a better way: provide feedback to the author then hide the question and wait for an edit instead. If an edit was made, the question goes straight back to triage for another round. If after a certain amount of time no no edit was made by the author, we probably want the system to automatically close the question.

### Some advantages

**We don't close everything that *can* be closed**, but focus on closing what should be closed and give authors a grace period to improve their questions.

**We cannot down-vote**. This may not seem to be an advantage at first, but I really think it is. Hide the question instead. It's not very motivating for new users to edit questions that accumulate down-votes. And at this point we don't have to: as long as the question is hidden from the community we don't have to judge the quality.

**We do not bind additional close votes**. Give the author enough time to edit and if he or she does not, just close the question automatically. This seems rather drastic, but I don't think it actually is. If the author is not happy with the decision, he or she can make a trivial edit to send it back to the queue.

### Summary

I think the goal should be not to be too harsh to new users without lowering the overall quality. I think that this proposal already would improve many aspects of the triage system.

Comment: SO is not hostile to beginners. SO is hostile to bad questions and it MUST stay like that. SO is not the place to learn "how to ask good question" (the web is already full of blogs explaining how to do that). IMO, regarding the primary goal of SO ( *building a knowledge repository about programming* ), the "Help and Improvement" queue is a waste of time and resources (99% of it should have been closed right away).

Comment: @ben75, I agree with you - still I don't think those two goals are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 4):

I disagree, will explain why. Regarding the advantages you mentioned,

> We don't close everything that can be closed, but focus on closing what should be closed and give authors a grace period to improve their questions.

Why would this be as a result of your proposal? We *do* focus on closing what should be closed and we do give authors unlimited time to improve their questions (if they're salvageable and worth fixing), such edited questions will be pushed to the "Reopen" queue and if they're worth reopening, they'll be.

If the question is hidden from the community, how would it benefit from constructive comments? We should enlighten posters by giving them feedback about their posts.

> We cannot down-vote...

I don't see how this one is an advantage, downvotes motivates more than upvotes. They're there to let you know that you should be improved, treat downvotes as constructive criticism and learn from them.

> We do not bind additional close votes.

As I mentioned before, if the question is salvageable, OP can edit their question and improve it, and in such cases, it'll be reopened.

Comment: Well, it seems that this is more controversial than I have expected. I must say I strongly disagree with your assumption that down-votes motivate more than up-votes. In fact, when I put together my question I had exactly the opposite in mind: heavily down-voted questions are rather deleted than improved by new users. When triage reviewers decide that a question cannot be answered and requires author interaction, I don't think more down-votes are helpful or constructive. I see that closing and eventually reopening is an option, but I feel that this is not the user friendliest way to go here.

Comment: Also, I feel the urge to not take the down-votes as constructive criticism and delete my question :)

Comment: @cel downvotes on meta doesn't mean your question is not good, they mean "I don't agree with you".